# If else expression compare not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want to perform a compare if @accid2 not equal @accid then roll back action, else perform insert.

My result of this trigger is even that is not match but it still insert into my table.

here is my code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TG_checkacctypehtl]
ON [dbo].[Accommodation_Hotel] INSTEAD OF INSERT 
AS 
DECLARE @accid NVARCHAR(50), @accid2 NVARCHAR(50),@hid NVARCHAR(50),@fsp NVARCHAR(50), @fc NVARCHAR(50), @sr NVARCHAR(50);
SELECT  @hid = i.hotel_id FROM INSERTED i;  
SELECT @fsp = i.facillities_swimming_pool FROM INSERTED i;
SELECT @fc = i.facillities_catering FROM INSERTED i;
SELECT @sr =  i.star_rating FROM INSERTED i;
SELECT  @accid2 = i.accommodation_id FROM INSERTED i; 
SELECT  @accid = accommodation_id FROM [dbo].[Accommodation] WHERE    accommodation_type= 'hotel' AND accommodation_id=@accid2; 
BEGIN 
BEGIN TRAN
SET NOCOUNT ON
PRINT @accid2
PRINT @accid
IF(@accid2 != @accid)
BEGIN
RAISERROR('Record Not Inserted, Accommodation ID is not a Hotel Id',16,1);   ROLLBACK; END 
ElSE BEGIN
INSERT INTO [dbo].[accommodation_hotel] (hotel_id,facillities_swimming_pool,facillities_catering,star_rating,accommodation_id) 
        VALUES (@hid,@fsp,@fc,@sr,@accid2);COMMIT;

END
END
```

*print is for check the value i get.

is that my logic error or my syntax error?

Comment: Besides the point, but it's generally a bad idea to do a commit or rollback inside a trigger.

Comment: What are the values for `@accid2` and `@accid`?

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statement that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT @id = u.id FROM Inserted u` - it's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite the whole trigger something like this...

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TG_checkacctypehtl]
ON [dbo].[Accommodation_Hotel] 
INSTEAD OF INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[accommodation_hotel] (hotel_id,facillities_swimming_pool,facillities_catering,star_rating,accommodation_id) 
SELECT i.hotel_id 
      ,i.facillities_swimming_pool
      ,i.facillities_catering
      ,i.star_rating
      ,i.accommodation_id
FROM inserted i 
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
               FROM [dbo].[Accommodation] a
               WHERE a.accommodation_type= 'hotel' 
               AND a.accommodation_id = i.accommodation_id)

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted i 
            WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
                               FROM [dbo].[Accommodation] a
                               WHERE a.accommodation_type= 'hotel' 
                               AND a.accommodation_id = i.accommodation_id)
            )
  BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Records with invalid Accommodation ID is not a Hotel Id not inserted',16,1);
  END
END
```

Insert the rows with valid accommodation ids and raise an error if there are any rows with invalid Hotel Ids, Also no need for all those variables.

Also triggers are fired for each transaction, not for each row. Your code assume there will only be one rows inserted ever in the table at a time.

Comment: may i know what the "1" and "a"  used for inside??

Comment: `1` is just a random value for the `EXISTS` operator, it doesnt have to `1` it can be anything, a `*` or even `NULL` will also work just fine. `a` is just an alias for the `[dbo].[Accommodation]` table.

Answer (score -1):

Should be IF(@accid2 <> @accid)

Comment: try ard, it same.....it will still insert into table if the accid and accid2 is not equal

Comment: `!=` is the same as `<>`

Comment: My bad.  Learned it as <>, never knew != was valid.  Thought it was a error.  Like many people, I deal with multiple languages and thought it was a miscast.